# wcf Sample project

Tags: wcf-client

I need a wcf Sample project that monitoring one of the database's tables and that kind of get the record for every change in the records and kind of send an Notify to clients.

help to me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some WCF examples
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154870/WCF-Service-Library-A-Good-Approach-for-WCF-Servic
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16765/WCF-Windows-Communication-Foundation-Example

However, for your other 2 requirements you need to put logics for the same